# hosting server on IOT and access from internet without port forwarding on router

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, portforwarding, ip-camera

I am developing my IOT device which has a server component that needs to be accessed from the internet. Well, I would like my clients to access it without configuring their home routers with port forwarding. I am ready to buy AWS instance or any other suggested intermediate servers. Can anybody recommend how to do it? I see IP cameras implement a similar concept.

Comment: You can use AWS EC2 instance and assign an elastic IP to it, so it can be accessed directly. You can find more information about EC2 instances [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts.html) and about elastic IP [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html).

Comment: There are some other ways as well but depends on your project

Comment: Do we have any other suggestions? I am working on a IP camera that needs video streaming to external network without configuring home routers.